# Where can I leave a post about my project?

Tags: support

Is there any place on Stack Exchange network where I can post some information about a project I am currently working on?

Comment: What do you mean? To advertise it or to ask for help about it? You can advertise your project as much as you want in your profile (e.g. via the "About" box or the "Website" field). Other than that, SE won't take kindly to you blatantly promoting your project across the site. If you want help on the project, it depends what it is...

Comment: I am voting this question up because you asked the question, and did not just go "spamming" links to your project everywhere. You seem to have concern for what is acceptable to the community, and I appreciate that.

Comment: Agree with Andrew -- nice that you asked! Now don't do it :p

Answer (score 15):

No.

If you want to advertise your project [buy an advert](https://stackoverflow.com/help/advertise).

Answer (score 1):

All Stack Exchange websites are Question + Answer sites.  The software that powers them is not a generic CMS, but a specialized Q+A site engine, and all sites have a similar policy.

Your project obviously does not qualify as a *question*.  If it already serves as a part of a completely practical *answer* to some kind of a question asked by someone else, you are free to offer such an answer.

I don't really expect that you would succeed in finding questions that will be directly and fully answered just by pointing to your project; which means that you should not post information about your project on Stack Exchange sites.

Even just looking for such questions may however provide inspiration to your project; you will see a sampling of real questions asked by people in your area.  That's the real benefit of the exercise.

Please be realistic when evaluating the possibility of answering a question by "pointing to yourself".  Make double sure that you don't overlook an operating system mismatch, previous better questions, or maybe a difference between a market ready library and a tentative project.  Do not answer a question just because you are looking for free advert space.  The community is known to close such "answers" promptly.  Be also very open about your relation to the project, to avoid any doubt about your motives; and stick to facts within the scope of the question.

Comment: This is a very dangerous path. Excessive self promotion is explicitly banned in the FAQ, so going round posting answer that do no more than pimp your project would be flagged and deleted very quickly.

Comment: To add to @ChrisF comment, that's even worse if it is a commercial project or the site has some sort of Ad-System on it. The possibility is very good that that would lead to Spam-Flags together with a reputation penalty. For new users that is also a very good way to get your account nuked as a spammer (from high orbit, as I'm assured).

Comment: Gentlemen, while I agree with you on what you say, I am proposing a something entirely different than excessive self promotion.  If I overlooked anything in your comments that the answer does not cover, please point it out.  (I was and am assuming that this question was  asked in good faith.  People point to their own online articles or other resources all the time, for the benefit of the site.)

Comment: @Jirka the problem is, this user's motivation is promotion of his project, at the outset. that colors his posts the wrong way. If his motivation was helping, and it just so happened his project solved a problem... that would be another thing. Still dangerous. I flag the posts you refer to all the time - by the hundreds. Self-promotion as.a goal is nit the intent of this site.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - The OP's existing 18 answers on SO look to me all helping.  Should we pick an example (of what you mention - somebody's plugs) and look at one together?  It still seems to me that the author of a post knows very well whether they are answering a question, or moving outside of the Q+A format.  Especially if they have a track record at the same site.

Comment: @JirkaHanika I'm not talking about his history, I'm talking about the answer to *this* question, which was basically, "how can I promote my project on this site?"

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Well, the hundreds of posts.  How they look exactly?  An example of what you mean would help me.  Do you automatically flag every post that contains the words "shameless plug"?  (That alone would be 592 posts right now.)  I just don't.

Comment: You don't have to flag them if you don't want.